# Unexpected Delay in Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, nsbutton

I have a method that gets the IBOutlet of another class by initializing an instance to the other class and then runs code that uses the references to the IBOutlets to set a memory address in another app.  The code runs fine but is periodically updated by a timer that I set up to refresh every 5 seconds.  The problem is that every 5 seconds the memory address is periodically changed to the wrong value and then back to the right value.  Here is my essential code:

```
#define OFF 0
#define ON 1
- (void)onOff:(id)sender {
    if ([[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state] == ON) {
        [helper setIntForAddress:0xFFFFFF value:1];
    }
    if ([[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state] == OFF) {
        [helper setIntForAddress:0xFFFFFF value:0];
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I call this code from anything other than a button press (ex. [self onOff:self]; ) It briefly sets the value to 0 and then back to 1.  My code worked fine when implemented inside the application controller; however, now it works but with this error.  If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What does this `setIntForAddress:value:` method do? Does it change the value of `[[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the method is somehow being called twice. Are you sure you're only calling it once? Check with the Instruments app to see if it is indeed being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that ***setIntForAddress:value:*** method changes the value of ***[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state]***. If so, just convert the two *if statements* into a single *if-else* block.

```
if ([[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state] == ON) {
    [helper setIntForAddress:0xFFFFFF value:1];
} else if ([[appDelegate buttonOutletName] state] == OFF) {
    [helper setIntForAddress:0xFFFFFF value:0];
}
```